# How to Refresh Android Listview with new value only

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying set my updated adapter in listview but I have a problem is that old value in list view is still remain there and below that new value is set so I just want to set only new refresh value in listview.

Comment: add some related code what you have tried yet then we will able to help you?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: its better to use RecyclerView..
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: For an ArrayAdapter, `adapter.clear()` then `adapter.add(data)` and then (optionally) `adapter.notfiyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: ListAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(), contactList,
                    R.layout.table_list_item, new String[]{
                    TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME, TAG_ORDER_AMOUNT, TAG_ORDER_STATUS, TAG_ORDER_DATE, TAG_ORDER_BY, TAG_COMMENT}, new int[]{R.id.txtcustomerName, R.id.txtorderamount, R.id.txtorderstatus, R.id.txtorderdate, R.id.txtorderby, R.id.txtcomment});

            setListAdapter(adapter1);
              ..............................................i have add this code in onpost() method

Comment: can anyone have solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**This is example for product list contain Product name and cost.**

**I taken `ProductDetails` entity class contain product name and price**

```
public class ProductDetails {
    String productName;
    int productPrice;

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public int getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(int productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }
}
```

in your `MainActivity.java` add this code,

```
        Button updateCostList = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateCostList);
        ListView costList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.costList);
        // create instance of custom adapter for custom list view
        customCostlistAdapter = new CustomCostlistAdapter();
        costList.setAdapter(customCostlistAdapter);

        // when we user click on update list details
        updateCostList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // we have set adapter properly
                if (customCostlistAdapter != null && customCostlistAdapter.getCount() > 0){

                    // update 2nd element from arraylist 
                    ProductDetails productDetails = new ProductDetails();
                    productDetails.setProductName("Updated product");
                    productDetails.setProductPrice(5555);
                    productCostDetails.set(2,productDetails);

                    // make changes in list
                    // this is magical line
                    customCostlistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
```

**Now create custom adapter for product cost details (For custom listview)**

```
    /**
     * Custom class for set product price details
     */
    private class CustomCostlistAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return productCostDetails.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View productCostDetailView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_product_costview,null);
            // create view for product
            TextView productName = (TextView)productCostDetailView.findViewById(R.id.txtProductName);
            TextView productPrice = (TextView)productCostDetailView.findViewById(R.id.txtProductPrice);
            //set values
            productName.setText(productCostDetails.get(position).getProductName());
            productPrice.setText(productCostDetails.get(position).getProductPrice()+"");

            return productCostDetailView;
        }
    }
```